# For the vector v = [2.0, -3.5, 5.1]: Find the L1 norm of v

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

Can you please help me to solve this question? I tried and my codes produce the following output 6.500769185258003 but still, the system says the wrong answer. Can you please tell me what I am missing? Is this the codes issues or I calculate in the wrong way.? Thanks in advance.

For the vector `v = [2.0, -3.5, 5.1]`:

- Find the L1 norm of `v`
- Return the result as a `float`

```
import numpy as np
import math
def calculate_l1_norm(v):
    '''
    INPUT: LIST or ARRAY (containing numeric elements)
    OUTPUT: FLOAT (L1 norm of v)
    calculate and return a norm for a given vector
    '''
    norm = 0
    for x in v:
        norm += x**2
    return math.sqrt(norm)
print(calculate_l1_norm([2.0,-3.5,5.1]))
```

Comment: You have calculated the L2 norm.

Comment: That's an L2 norm you're computing, not an L1 norm.

Comment: L1 norm:  change the line to be. `for x in v:`  `norm += abs(x)` `return norm`

Comment: Or a one liner: `sum(abs(i) for i in v)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one liner to calc the [L1 norm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/L1-Norm.html).

```
sum(abs(i) for i in v)
```

---

#### Update:

Updated answer to provide a working example, to address OP's "it's not working" comment.

```
def calculate_l1_norm(v) -> float:
    """Return L1 normalisation as float."""
    return sum(abs(i) for i in v)
```

Use:

```
>>> calculate_l1_norm([2.0, -3.5, 5.1])
```

Output:

```
10.6
```

Comment: Still, it's not working now it produces answer 0.0 which is wrong again.

Comment: @TauqeerAhmad - Thank you for your comment. The statement works as mentioned. I've updated the answer to show a use-example. Hope this helps.